# How do I get the form id by using Google form API

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, cloud

I have a service account and have already authenticated for the same for Google form API,
and I want to get one response data from the form by using google forms API.

HTTP request::
GET [https://forms.googleapis.com/v1beta/forms/**{formId}**/responses](https://forms.googleapis.com/v1beta/forms/**%7BformId%7D**/responses)

- How do i get the formid without using Embed HTML code.

I am currently referring to this link.
https://developers.google.com/forms/api/reference/rest/v1beta/forms.responses/get

Answer (score 0):

I am finding the solution to get the form id without using Embed HTML code.

There is no method to list all forms with the Forms API. However,
You can use the Drive API [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list), where you can specify the `mimeType = application/vnd.google-apps`. form with the [query parameter q.](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files)

For example URL

https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=mimeType%3A%20%27application%2Fvnd.google-apps.form%27